# Snmp4j agent with snmp v2 instead of v3

Tags: snmp, agent, snmp4j

I have successfully working the snmp4j sample agent.

http://www.snmp4j.org/agent/doc/org/snmp4j/agent/example/SampleAgent.html

This works with snmp v3 but what must I change to get the agent working with snmp v2 instead of v3?

An alternative solution with a derived class of the BaseAgent is also welcome.

Iam using the snmp4j agent version 2.5.3

Thank you in advance